# How to use insertHTML to add a correctly closed image tag to a document

Tags: java, html

I'm trying to use **HTMLEditorKit** to add an image to a document. The method works but it seems there is no way to obtain a closed tag.

I've tried

`htmlKit.insertHTML(htmlDoc, caretPos, "<img src=\"img.jpg\" alt=\"\" />", 0, 0, HTML.Tag.IMG);`

and

`htmlKit.insertHTML(htmlDoc, caretPos, "<img src=\"img.jpg\" alt=\"\"></img>", 0, 0, HTML.Tag.IMG);`

but the resulting HTML tag is never closed

`<img src="img.jpg" alt="" >`

Comment: try to use `\/` instead of only `/` in your first try.

Comment: `img` is an empty tag. It doesn't need to be closed.